# Can I use Jquery to find and then set the width of an image?

Tags: jquery, width

I am using a slideshow script that needs the dimensions of every image for it to work properly.  There are going to be some 50+ images that a client would have to add dimensions too.

Is there a script I can use that will find the width of all the images in an unordered list with an ID of "scroller", and then set the width just like it'd be set within the image tag?

If somebody could help me write it, and possibly explain what each section does, I would greatly appreciate it.

And if you are looking for code, here it is.

Before JQuery code.

```
<ul id="scroller">
<li><img src="image.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="image.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="image.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="image.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

After JQuery code.

```
<ul id="scroller">
<li><img src="image.jpg" width="100"></li>
<li><img src="image.jpg" width="350"></li>
<li><img src="image.jpg" width="70"></li>
<li><img src="image.jpg" wudth="250"></li>
</ul>
```

The images would have different widths, but all the same height.

Comment: why not just set the height? if you leave width auto, it will determine the width on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could. It's very intuitive really.

```
$('image selector').width(); //to access width
$('image selector').width(N); //to set width to Npx.
```

In order to loop through all of them, you'll use `.each()`.

```
$('#scroller img').each(function() {
    //Do stuff width each image. $(this).
}
```

---

You may want to know that you can grab the existing width and set it, but only after the element is fully loaded. This may cause a bit of jumpiness on older browsers, so it would be worth it to hide the images, grab the existing dimensions, do the transformation, and then fade them all in at the same time or something pretty looking like that. 
Thanks @Whetstone

---

```
$(function() {

    $('#scroller img').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('width', $(this).width());
    });

});
```

Comment: You may want to clarify that you can grab the existing width and set it, but only after the element is fully loaded.  This may cause a bit of jumpiness on older browsers, so it would be worth it to hide the images, grab the existing dimensions, do the transformation, and then fade them all in at the same time or something pretty looking like that.

Comment: @Truth, I understand your code, thank you.  Though, I am a bit confused on how I might build it to be a completed code to loop through all my images. Could you help?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve, how are you setting the width? by what criteria. @Ryan

Comment: @Truth I need to find the width of each image and then set it rather than manually setting each image within the image tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#scroller img').each(function(){
var t=$(this);
    t.load(function(){
        t.attr('width', t.attr('width'));
    });
});
```

.each scrolls through all the images within the #scroller `ul`.

jQuery can only get the width of the image after it has been fully loaded, hence the `.load`.

The rest is pretty straightforward. Use the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/) docs for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#scroller').find('img').each(function() {
   // $(this).width()
   // Implement your stuff
});
```